# Was Vision ever called by that name in Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

I know his name is Vision because of SFF.SE, but the nearest thing I remember in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* is someone (Stark?) mentioning something about a vision, but not as the new android's name.

Was he ever called by his name, Vision, or was he "formally" named, or is it an assumed thing?

Comment: There’s literally a TV series named *WandaVision* in MCU.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, he is referred to as "The Vision" several times in the movie.

Initially, you're correct that the word wasn't used as a name, it was used to describe Stark's "vision" of a new AI. Ultron also later refers to the android as "my Vision."

However, the Avengers do use the word in such a way that it's clear they've decided that his name is "The Vision". For example, Tony refers to him by name during the climactic battle:

> Stark: FRIDAY! The Vision?
>
> FRIDAY: Boss, it's working. He's burning Ultron out of the 'net, he won't escape through there.

Also, in the final scene, Thor decides to leave

> The Mind Stone

with the android:

> Thor: If he can wield the hammer, he can keep [spoiler]. It's safe with the Vision. And these days, safe is in short supply.

Comment: Also, during his birth scene, Steve asks, "why does your 'Vision' sound like Jarvis?"

Comment: isn't vision a physical form of Jarvis? Wouldn't his name be Jarvis then?

Comment: No, he's not really a physical form of Jarvis... Jarvis forms the core of his "intelligence" but he's also many other parts mixed in. If anything, he's a manifestation of the Mind Gem using Jarvis as a foundation.